# Возвращаемое значение пропущено: "scanf" Код : C6031 Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c, visual-studio, функции

При объявлении scanf, строки кода подчёркиваются желтой волнистой линией. Как ни старался решить эту проблему, ничего не выходит.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  float x, y, res;
  scanf("%f", &x);
  scanf("%f", &y);
  res = x / y;
  printf("Result: %.2f\n", res);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вы в курсе, что `scanf` возвращает значение? Которое стоит и проверить...

Comment: Не совсем понял Вас

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#:~:text=behavior%20is%20undefined.-,Return%20value,-1%2D3)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переписать так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  float x, y, res;
  if (scanf("%f", &x) != 1) return 1;
  if (scanf("%f", &y) != 1) return 1;
  res = x / y;
  printf("Result: %.2f\n", res);
  return 0;
}
```